# Codecademy Ruby Programming A Night at the Movies

Tags: ruby

I'm learning how to code in Ruby from the Codecademy website. I'm having trouble getting my code to execute. I've been working on the "update" branch of the case statement.

```
movies = {
oceansEleven: 4.5
}

puts "Would you like to Add, Update, Display or Delete?"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
    print "What movie would you like to add"
    title = gets.chomp
if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    print "How would you rate this movie? (1-5)"
    rating = gets.chomp
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added with a #{rating} rating."
else
    puts "That movie already exists! It's rating is #{rating}"
end
when "update"
    print "What movie would you like to update?
    title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title].nil?
        puts "Movie not found!"
else
    puts "What is your new rating for the movie? (1-5)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been updated with a #{rating} rating."
end
when "display"
    puts "Movies"
when "delete"
    puts "Deleted!"
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```

Here are the error messages that I'm receiving:

```
(ruby):23: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
    puts "Movie not found!"
               ^
(ruby):25: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
puts "What is your new rating for the movie? (1-5)"
```

Comment: I recommend you use an editor with syntax colouring - I can see the problem here on Stack Overflow due to its colouring: `print "What movie would you like to update?` is missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three lines above, you forgot to close a string literal. Add a " there.

Change

```
 print "What movie would you like to update?
```

to

```
 print "What movie would you like to update?"
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a bad news for you: You are not perfect.! =D (and here is a hint: nobody is as we all make mistakes =] ). Glad I could help. Cheers.